# Can firebase cloud functions emulator invoke triggers with production firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to test a Firebase cloud function on an emulator with real production firestore. When I start up my functions emulator, I get an error `i functions[sendPushOnNewMessage]:function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.` Interestingly, I can read from firestore (from production data), but firebase emulator refuses to allow these functions to start.

```
❯ firebase emulators:start --only functions
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
⚠  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to /Users/.../functions/3afae-a81e699d1cf0.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
⚠  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.
>  Starting up...
i  functions[createUserRecord]: function ignored because the auth emulator does not exist or is not running.
i  functions[sendPushOnNewMessage]: function ignored because the firestore emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

Here is how I am using service account to setup (I know this works since I can read documents):

```
// Service account initialization.
let serviceAccount = require('./3afae-a81e699d1cf0.json');
var initOptions = {}
emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional.
if (process.env.FUNCTIONS_EMULATOR) {
  initOptions.credential = admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
}
admin.initializeApp(initOptions);
const firestore = admin.firestore();
```

Example of my trigger function:

```
exports.sendPushOnNewMessage = functions.firestore.document('chats/{chatID}/messages/{messageID}').onCreate((change, context) => {
    console.log("Trigger called")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Firebase Firestore emulator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58932851/how-does-firebase-firestore-emulator-work)

Comment: I guess the reason why I was still confused by that answer is that if you don't setup firestore emulator, you can still access production (read data for example). Also, the CLIT warns `⚠  functions: The Cloud Firestore emulator is not running, so calls to Firestore will affect production.`

Comment: That's correct. By using `firebase emulators:start --only functions`, you are just starting the emulator for functions that don't include Firestore. If you would like to run the Firebase emulator for multiple products (Functions and Firestore) just run `firebase emulators:start`. More information can be found in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#run_the_emulator_suite).